# Quarkus Swagger MongoDB ObjectId Format

Tags: mongodb, swagger-ui, quarkus, objectid

I'am writting app with quarkus-resteasy and mongodb. After quarkus OpenAPI has been installed, I saw that swagger UI does not correctly showing ObjectID format.

[image: [Look at the image][1].]

I am would like  to see something like "61338f5b47bfc65136b5de30". How globally set ObjectID output format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because an objectId its what it is, thouse are the fields inside and what openapi is interpreting.

You can override what is being generated using the `@Schema` annotation, providing a format, an example and a type, in this case String, you can control what your swagger will contain.

```
@Schema(description = "Identifier of the Whatever", type = SchemaType.STRING, format = "XXXXXX", example="<Insert and example here>")
```

Because this is a value rather than a class that you can modify I think that you will need to put this annotation in all your DTO's that use these type.

Another option is using a Wrapper object, but this may modify your json structure depending on how you implement it.

Answer (score 0):

I originally thought this was working as it does replace the ObjectId with a string in the model.  However when I return that model in a PUT or POST the OpenAPI doesn't reference the model e.g. $ref: '#/components/schemas/A2dlDataSourceOnboarding'

Rather for the PUT & POST it ignores the model above and says the content returned is:

content:
application/json:
schema:
type: object
properties:
id:
type: object
allOf:
- $ref: '#/components/schemas/ObjectId'
example: d76d6cb6cba140e0a308643c
dataSourceName:
type: string
dataSourceUserName:
type: string

So the OpenAPI is repeating the same model contents with the old/replaced ObjectId.  Why doesn't OpenAPI always reference the model via $ref?

The current OpenAPI is broken as has errors that ObjectId is not defined.

Comment: The OpenAPI is also incorrect for GET operations, that get by name for example.  The only place this work correctly is when getting an array of resources, e.g. the get all endpoint.  None of the others use the $ref: '#/components/schemas/A2dlDataSourceOnboarding' reference to the correct schema component.